# Pass through constness from a struct to its pointer and reference members

Tags: c++, constants

I've got a struct with a pointer in it.  I'd like to make it so if a struct instance is const, then the contents of its pointer cannot be modified.

```
struct Foo {};

struct Bar {
    Foo /*const goes here if `const Bar`*/ *foo;
};

void f(Bar& bar) {
    *bar.foo = Foo(); // OK
}

void g(const Bar& bar) {
    *bar.foo = Foo(); // OK - but should be error
}
```

Is there a way to pass through constness from the struct to its pointer and reference members?

Answer (score 6):

Encapsulation to the rescue!

Just marshall access through an interface:

```
struct Bar {
  Foo * getFoo() { return foo; }
  Foo const * getFoo() const { return foo; }
private:
  Foo *foo;
};

void f(Bar& bar) {
    *bar.getfoo() = Foo(); // OK
}

void g(const Bar& bar) {
    *bar.getfoo() = Foo(); // Error!
}
```

Comment: That should work...  I'll upvote instead of accepting just because it bothers me to have to use an accessor method.

Comment: @jcarpenter Why would that bother you? Having an interface that is disconnected from the implementation (which is what you are asking for) is the whoe point of encapsulation. And public member variables should be a rare exception, not the default for anything non-trivial.

Comment: This may betray my noobishness, but I like working with plain old data structures, and using top-level methods (rather than member functions) to operate on them.  The () are two extra characters to type whenever I need that member.

Answer (score 2):

You are fighting the language, don't do that. It's like swimming upstream - you will only tire yourself and not like the result.

Your problem can be fixed by using private data and a member function to do the work:

```
struct Foo {};

struct Bar {
   void reset() {
      *foo = Foo();
   }
private:
    Foo  *foo;
};

void f(Bar& bar) {
    bar.reset();   // OK
}

void g(const Bar& bar) {
    bar.reset();   // fails, as reset is not declared const
}
```

Comment: Well, the "`*Foo = foo()`" lines in `f` and `g` aren't important in my case, that's just an example of something that could only be done on a non-const pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Make const propaging smart pointer:

```
template<typename T>
struct const_ptr : std::unique_ptr<T> {
    using std::unique_ptr<T>::unique_ptr;

    const T& operator*() const {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>::operator*();
    }

    const T* operator->() const {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>::operator->();
    }

    T& operator*() {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>::operator*();
    }

    T* operator->() {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>::operator->();
    }
};
```

Then, trying to mutate the object reference by a const `const_ptr` will result in an error:

```
const_ptr<int> iptr = std::make_unique<int>(6);

*iptr = 7; // okay

const auto ciptr = std::move(iptr);

*ciptr = 2; // error
```

However, please note that since we extends `std::unique_ptr` publicly, his function are still available. You might want to use private inheritance and using all other function except our custom one:

```
template<typename T>
struct const_ptr : private std::unique_ptr<T> {
    using std::unique_ptr<T>::unique_ptr;

    // Implement our operators like above

    using std::unique_ptr<T>::release;
    using std::unique_ptr<T>::reset;
    // .. all other public functions
};
```

Comment: I like that a lot.  I've modified it to this: https://pastebin.com/GdZNEjCt  Importantly, only the struct has to know about the special `const_ptr` type.  All of its callers can work with a raw pointer.

Comment: @jcarpenter I suggest you to implement a `get` function in your `const_ptr` class that returns the raw pointer for compatibility, and also to overload the `->` operator to make possible to call members. Also, be careful to not store owning pointers in that class. Raw owning pointer are bad mmkay?

Comment: @uillaume-racicot mmkay.